# Replacing a line of text in .ini using PowerShell

Tags: ini, powershell-ise

Hello I am trying to run a script in PowerShell ISE to replace a line of text in an .ini file.

```
(Get-Content C:\ProgramData\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking12\nssystem.ini) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "Default NAS Address=","Default NAS Address=BHPAPPDGN01V" } | Set-Content C:\ProgramData\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking12\nssystem.ini
```

This script works BUT when I run it multiple times the .ini text keeps getting added to the end of the line giving me a bunch of junk.

> Example: Ran script 4 times "Default NAS
>   Address=BHPAPPDGN01VBHPAPPDGN01VBHPAPPDGN01VBHPAPPDGN01V"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
(Get-Content C:\ProgramData\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking12\nssystem.ini) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'Default NAS Address=.*','Default NAS Address=BHPAPPDGN01V' } | Set-Content C:\ProgramData\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking12\nssystem.ini
```

I just try to use a regex to select evrything behind the `=`.

Comment: Very great, simple command which is extremely useful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

replace

"-replace "Default NAS Address="

to

"-replace "Default NAS Address=[A-Z0-9]*"

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't keen on the suggestions above so here's my solution in case anyone stumbles in from Google and finds it useful.

Contents of test.ini

```
[Other Parameter] = Something
[My Parameter] = What I wouldnt give for a change of heart
[Other Parameter] = Nothing
```

My solution:

```
$MyString = Get-Content "C:\Test_Script\test.ini"
$NewString = $MyString.replace("[My Parameter] = What I wouldnt give for a change of heart","[My Parameter] = I gave my heart for a piece of string")
Set-Content -Path "C:\Test_Script\test.ini"  -Value $NewString
```

Changed contents of test.ini

```
[Other Parameter] = Something
[My Parameter] = I gave my heart for a piece of string
[Other Parameter] = Nothing
```